# Applying same style to all the comments on the page

Tags: comments, css

I have this code below:

`#comment-1, #comment-2, #comment-3 {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
}`

This CSS is to format the comments for them to be 70% of the parent div's width.  I see where it breaks after 3 comments, how do I get it to apply to all the comments on the page regardless of the number?

Comment: Have a look at the HTML source generated by a comment in your site.  There should be a number of classes in addition to the ID `comment-{#}`. Try using one of those classes in your CSS instead of the individual comment ID numbers.

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress will add some classes to each comment with `comment_class()`. All *comments* get the class `comment`. So you can style comments with:

```
.comment {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

See `wp-includes/comment-template.php` for more context.